# Condtional Covarianz Problem

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence, covariance

i have on Friday a presentation and i have one small problem.
Let $ X_1,...,X_n$ be independent Random Variables. Let $f: \Omega^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define $Z:=f(X_1,...,X_n)$.
Define also:
\begin{align*}
E_{(i)}[Z]&:=E[Z \vert X_1,...,X_i], \\
E^{(i)}[Z]&:=E[Z \vert X_1,...,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n].
\end{align*}
Now let $T$ be $(X_1,...,X_i)$ measureable.
Then following equation holds:
\begin{equation*}
E[Cov^{(i)}(T,Z)]=E[Z(T-E^{(i)}[T]]
\end{equation*}
I dont know why this should be true.

I wanted to show this with the defintion:
\begin{align*}
E[Cov^{(i)}(T,Z)]=E[E^{(i)}[ZT]-E^{(i)}[Z]E^{(i)}[T]]
\end{align*}
now when i compare this with the result, i see $E^{(i)}[ZT]=ZT$ and $ E^{(i)}[Z]=Z$. Hence $Z$ and $ZT$ must be $(X_1,...,X_{i-1},X_{i+1},...,X_n)$ measureable but i dont know why this should be true. I would really appreciate some help. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that 
$$
 E[E^{(i)}[ZT]]=E[ZT]
$$
hence it suffices to check that 
$$
 E\left[ E^{(i)}[Z]E^{(i)}[T]\right]= E\left[ ZE^{(i)}[T]\right].
$$
Denoting $\mathcal F$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_j$, $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus \{i\}$, we get that 
$$
 E\left[ E^{(i)}[Z]E^{(i)}[T]\right]=E[E[Z\mid \mathcal F]E[T\mid \mathcal F]]
$$
and since $E[Z\mid \mathcal F]$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable, we get that 
$$
E[ZE[T\mid \mathcal F]\mid \mathcal F]
$$
and the result follows by taking the expectation.